# Running time of a long array of fixed size

Tags: java, time, big-o

Does the running time of an algorithm depend on the length of an array?
I understand if the length of an array is unknown we will say the running time of the following algorithm is O(n).

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Size of array: ");

    int lengthOfArray = sc.nextInt();
    int[] longArray = new int[lengthOfArray];

    for (int i = 0; i < longArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Hello" + i);
    }

}
```

However, if the length of an array is known and fixed. Will it be considered as constant time i.e. O(1) or is it still considered as O(n).

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] longArray = new int[99];

    for (int i = 0; i < longArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Hello" + i);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is somewhat subjective.  Strictly speaking, both code snippets are `O(n)` where `n` is the size of the array.  If you know the array is fixed, then you may offset that from your balance sheet by saying it is a constant time known penalty.  But it doesn't change the running time dynamics of the second loop.

Comment: Yes, If your array is of a fixed size and it does not vary with the size of the input it is O(1) since it can be expressed as c * O(1) = O(1), with c being some constant.

Comment: This is where one must make the distinction between time *complexity* and *actual execution* time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the complexity of the algorithm would be a constant. That's because the complexity will be always the same. (See I use complexity and not a running time because there is a difference actually).

It is O(n) for a loop which is not known because the task varies according to n (it can be more complex for milion records and less complex for 5). It still linear complexity though.

If we know the length n=5 then it becomes O(5) which is basically 5*O(1) and since constant numbers are not taken into account it becomes O(1) complexity.

It doesn't mean that if you know the number of elements the running time of the program will be less. It means that the running time will be a constant (because the complexity is constant).

Answer (score 1):

Time complexity: *O(n)* means your method running time is determined by the **input**.

It's a term used to communicate among developers to see what's the best among solutions to the same problem.

A nice explanation from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity):

> An algorithm is said to take linear time, or O(n) time, if its time complexity is O(n). Informally, this means that the running time increases at most linearly with the size of the input. More precisely, this means that there is a constant c such that the running time is at most cn for every input of size n. For example, a procedure that adds up all elements of a list requires time proportional to the length of the list, if the adding time is constant, or, at least, bounded by a constant.

Normally we need to consider not only *time* but *space* complexity based on the problem itself to select the proper solution.